# How to insert a hash to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a file `file.txt`, which has an array, which includes hashes:

```
[{:name "Muhammad"},{:name "Mahmoud"}]
```

I'm trying to read it by:

```
$list = File.readlines('file.txt')
```

I then add `hash` to the array:

```
$list << hash
```

The code works, but it creates an array inside an array:

```
["[{:name "/Mohammed/"},{:name "/Mahmoud/"}]"{:name "Ahmed"}]
```

When I instead read the file with:

```
$list = File.read('file.txt')
```

and then add `hast` [sic] to the array:

```
$list << hash
```

I'm actually adding `hash` to the array:

```
$list << hash
```

It gives this error:

```
can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)
```

How can I add a hash to an array?

Comment: `[{:name "Muhammad"},{:name "Mahmoud"}]` throws error (it is not a valid Hash or Array), I wonder how this code works...

Comment: The file contains characters only, no arrays or other Ruby objects. Let's say those characters are `'[{:name "Muhammad"},{:name "Mahmoud"}]'`. You can read that into a string: `str = File.read(file.txt) #=> "[{:name \"Muhammad\"},{:name \"Mahmoud\"}]"`. (No global variable here, please!). If `hash #=> { :a=>1 }`, say, `str << hash` will raise the exception you mentioned because `<<`'s argument must be a string.

Comment: Serhat, you need `[{:name=>"Muhammad"},{:name=>"Mahmoud"}]` or `[{name: "Muhammad"},{name: "Mahmoud"}]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I'm fully aware what's missing or mistyped, I just wondered - given the example - how this could work...

Comment: karatedog, then you dont see all of my code, how can you make so a comment , the code is working well but rewriting the file, i'm wondering it too,
Cary, I used global variable here cause i'm accesing this value from a lot function, and adding local variable to this functions is not so healty ( in my opinnion), and i didnt knowing that << operants arguement must be a string, i'm a new coder, i'm newly learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `readlines` and `read` are doing, as well as the contents of your file. Let's start with these things:

1. Files do not contain arrays or hashes - they contain text that perhaps can be parsed into arrays or hashes.
2. `File.read` reads the contents of a file into a string.
3. `File.readlines` reads the contents of a file into an array containing strings, where each string is one line of the file. It is (roughly) equivalent to `File.read('filename.txt').split("\n")`.

So, consider your file, which contains (corrected to valid Ruby syntax)

```
[{name: "Muhammad"},{name: "Mahmoud"}]
```

Though it looks to you like an array containing hashes, the brackets have no semantic meaning. Let's read it:

```
> data = File.read('file.txt')
 => "[{name: \"Muhammad\"},{name: \"Mahmoud\"}]\n"
```

Note a few things:

- There are quotes surrounding your data - it is a string
- The quotes in your file (`"Muhammad"`) are escaped
- There is a `\n` at the end of the string, signifying a newline

We can ask `data` what it is, and we can print it to see that it is indeed your file contents without any escaping:

```
> data.class
 => String
> puts data
[{name: "Muhammad"},{name: "Mahmoud"}]
 => nil
```

Now let's try `File.readlines`:

```
> lines = File.readlines('file.txt')
 => ["[{name: \"Muhammad\"},{name: \"Mahmoud\"}]\n"]
```

Notice brackets surrounding the same string we had before. This is an array containing a single string that was the first (only) line in your file.

```
> lines.class
 => Array
> lines.size
 => 1
> puts lines.first
[{name: "Muhammad"},{name: "Mahmoud"}]
 => nil
> lines.first == data
 => true
```

Now we can get to the error you're seeing. When you used `readlines` and then added `hash`, you were adding a hash to an array. This is perfectly legal in Ruby because you can have arrays containing elements of different types. When you added `hash`, you ended up with an array containing a string and a hash.

```
> hash = {name: "Ahmed"}
 => {:name=>"Ahmed"}
> lines << hash
 => ["[{name: \"Muhammad\"},{name: \"Mahmoud\"}]\n", {:name=>"Ahmed"}]
> lines.map(&:class)
 => [String, Hash]
> lines.size
 => 2
```

But, when you tried to add your hash to the result of `read`, you were adding a hash to a string, which Ruby won't do.

```
> data << hash
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

So to answer your title question, you *can* add a hash to an array, you just didn't realize you had, and your array didn't initially contain the data you expected it to.

To read your file in as a Ruby array containing hashes, you can use `eval`, which executes a string containing Ruby code. This is not generally advisable, because for example if you run it on data someone else provided, it could contain code you don't really want to be executing. Since you control this file and it's your own data, it's safe enough in this case.

```
> real_data = eval(File.read('file.txt'))
 => [{:name=>"Muhammad"}, {:name=>"Mahmoud"}]
> real_data.class
 => Array
> real_data.first
 => {:name=>"Muhammad"}
> real_data << hash
 => [{:name=>"Muhammad"}, {:name=>"Mahmoud"}, {:name=>"Ahmed"}]
```

Now you have a Ruby array containing Ruby hashes, and you can add another hash the way you were expecting to.

Comment: I learned so more things via your this answer, thanks a lot, my code is worked via use eval .